# Jenkins gets stuck after android terminal is rebooted

Tags: jenkins, android-reboot

We are downloading package from artifactory and installing on Android device with OS 8.1.0 using Jenkins.

After the installation we need to reboot Android device, framework used robot framework with Appium to run testcases on Android device(rooted).

Installation is successful on Android device, but After the reboot Jenkins gets stuck, and Never comes out.

To reboot used below commands

```
${result} =            run process          adb     -s   ${device_id}   root     shell=True

${result} =            run process          adb     -s   ${device_id}   reboot     shell=True
```

This reboots terminal but Jenkins then gets stuck and not able to run next sanity testcases using robot framework.

Is there a way in which Jenkins can still work after Android device is rebooted ?

Answer (score 1):

run process          adb     -s   ${device_id}   root     shell=True

run process          adb     -s   ${device_id}   reboot     shell=True

sleep   120

run process          adb     -s   ${device_id}   root     shell=True

This worked.